# Unsubscription Link in an external site

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, unsubscriber

we have now in our newsletter template the unsubscription link %%unsub_center_url%% to unsubscribe to our newsletter.

We are now creating on our website an unsubscription center where the user can choose between different frequency (es. 3 Emails x Week, 1 x Week, Unsubscribe).

I know that is possible create something similar only if we are using the Microsite or the Landing Pages of Exact Target.

Would it be possible then to connected the unsubscription link from the external website to the exact target unsubscription center? If yes, how?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Best Regards,
Massimo

Answer (score 1):

The %%unsub_center_url%% URL is unique per email send.  It contains encoded data relating to the subscriber and the specific email send and can only be decoded by the Salesforce Marketing Cloud platform.

If you plan to handle subscription statuses externally, you will need to push status changes back to Salesforce Marketing Cloud by either API calls or file drops to the the FTP.

Comment: You can also have SFMC Support update the `%%unsub_center_url%%` to point to your external page, which is nice since you won't have to update your existing templates to transition to the new unsubscribe page.

Comment: Interesting,    Is subscriber data passed in the URL in that case?

Comment: You may be able to treat it as you would the Web-Analytics Connector string and include whatever personalization/variables you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. So the only way to change the status for the users is only via API calls or FTP right?
For the unsubscription link I thought to change all the links with the url of the  website but this seems really smart. Thank you Adam.

Comment: Just to clarify further, the act of dropping the file on the FTP will not change the subscriber status.  You will need to run an import activity on the file as well.